# uninitialized copy error

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, allocator

I'm currently encountering an error while experimenting with my own vector class. To be more specific, it is a templated class, using the std::allocator class for memory allocation purposes. To be even more specific, the error is in my range constructor function where it takes in 2 input iterators and uses the "uninitialized_copy" function for copying purposes. Here is a stub of the code

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, typename allocator_type = std::allocator<T>>
class vector
{
public:

// fill ctor 2
vector (size_t n, const T& val,
        const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type())
  : my_alloc(alloc),
    begin_(my_alloc.allocate(n)),
    end_(begin_ + n),
    size_(n),
    capacity_(n)
{
  std::uninitialized_fill(begin(), end(), val);
}

// range ctor
template <typename InputIterator>
vector (InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
      const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type())
  : my_alloc(alloc),
    size_(0),
    begin_(0),
    end_(0),
    capacity_(0)
{
  // Poor method for finding input container size, a better solution perhaps?
  InputIterator f = first;
  while (f++ != last)
  ++size_;

  begin_ = my_alloc.allocate(size());
  end_ = begin_ + size();
  capacity_ = size();

  std::uninitialized_copy(first, last, begin_);
}

  T* begin() { return begin_; }
  T* end() { return end_; }
  size_t size() { return size_; }
  size_t capacity() { return capacity_; }

private:
  allocator_type my_alloc;
  size_t size_, capacity_;
  T* begin_, *end_;
};

int main()
{
  vector<int> lst(10, 5);
  vector<int> lst2(lst.begin(), lst.end());
}
```

Now when i compile, i receive an error where it says something about "no type named value_type in struct std::iterator_traits, which is weird as my other types of constructors such as a the fill and copy constructor is fine. In addition, i also noticed that the compiler deduced the "InputTterator" type to be of "int" instead of "int*".

I've been pulling my hair out for the past few hours trying to debug it, but just cant seem to find any solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Edit: Sorry! mistake on my part. It was not intentional to send 2 ints as part of the template parameters. I have edited the code above. It now has a proper fill ctor and a range ctor. The main function now creates 2 vectors based on these ctors. The errors still remain. Again, huge mistake on my part!

Comment: Explain how `(10,5)` constitutes a pair of *iterators*. You have no constructor besides your range-constructor, and it takes two like parameters and a default valued allocator. Your two `int` values match that solitary constructor in declaration, but clearly not in use. So... don't do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i also noticed that the compiler deduced the "InputTterator" type to be of "int" instead of "int*".

Well of course it did, you passed `int`s a arguments to the constructor:

```
vector<int> lst(10, 5);  // what else can it deduce than int?
```

The error you get is because specialization `iterator_traits<int>` used inside `uninitialized_copy` indeed doesn't have `value_type` member.

What you should do instead (to avoid going over the input range solely to get its size) is something like this (partialy pseudocode):

```
  InputIterator f = first;
  size_t current_size = 0;
  while (f != last) {
      if (current_size < size_) {
          new (begin+current_size) T(*f);
          ++current_size;
      } else {
          // allocate new buffer and copy any
          // existing elements over
          // (think about exception safety here)
      }
      ++f;
  }
```

This is the best you can do with input iterators. Another option is to check the iterator category of `InputIterator` so that when it allows arithmetic you can tag-dispatch to an implementation that calculates the size upfront.

EDIT (in response to edit of OP):

So your problem is that the constructor template with two iterators is called where you don't want it to. The same problem was present in standard library's vector class before C++11. The standard solves by saying that that constructor doesn't participate in overload resolution when the type deduced is not an iterator. You can do the same by using SFINAE:

```
template <typename InputIterator,
    typename ValueType = typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type>
vector (InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
      const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

Now, when `std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type` does not exist, overload resolution will discard the overload during template argument substitution and the other one will be selected instead.

Comment: Sorry! i edited the code above. It was not intentional to input "ints" as the template parameters, it was supposed to be 2 iterators.

Comment: @user3833701 You still got the same problem. It's not the first constructor that gets called in `vector<int> lst(10, 5);`, it's the templated one because it's a better match.